# Application that displays stocks based on user-entered stock codes

Tags: android

My application is not working as intended, it displays 0.00 when I run the program. How do I format my code or add some more elements such that it actually accesses the webpage? I have the access codes in my Manifest file, and my strings.xml and activity_main.xml don't seem to be giving any trouble. I'm mainly just confused whether I am actually understanding what all components to put in the java file for the app to access the internet.

My code snippet:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "HttpExample";
    private EditText urlText;
    private TextView textView;
    private Editable stock_symbol;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   
        urlText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        stock_symbol = urlText.getText();
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    }
    public void myClickHandler(View view) {
        // Gets URL from UI's text field.
        String stringUrl = urlText.getText().toString();
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new DownloadWebpageText().execute(stringUrl);
        } else {
            textView.setText("No network connection available.");
        }
    }

     /*Uses AsyncTask to create a task away from the main UI thread. This task takes a 
      * URL string and uses it to create an HttpUrlConnection. Once the connection
      * has been established, the AsyncTask downloads the contents of the webpage as
      * an InputStream. Finally, the InputStream is converted into a string, which is
      * displayed in the UI by the AsyncTask's onPostExecute method.*/
     private class DownloadWebpageText extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            String symbol = result.substring(result.indexOf('>') + 1, result.lastIndexOf('<'));
            textView.setText(symbol);
       }
     // Given a URL, establishes an HttpUrlConnection and retrieves
     // the web page content as a InputStream, which it returns as
     // a string.
     private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
         InputStream is = null;
         // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved web page content.
         int len = 500;
         try {
             URL url = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + stock_symbol + "&f=k1");
             HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
             conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
             conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
             conn.setDoInput(true);
             // Starts the query
             conn.connect();
             int response = conn.getResponseCode();
             Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
             is = conn.getInputStream();

             // Convert the InputStream into a string
             String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
             return contentAsString;

         // Confirms InputStream is closed after the app is finished using it.
         } finally {
             if (is != null) {
                 is.close();
             } 
         }
     }
     // Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
     public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
         Reader reader = null;
         reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");        
         char[] buffer = new char[len];
         reader.read(buffer);
         return new String(buffer);
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
         Reader reader = null;
         reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");        
         char[] buffer = new char[len];
         reader.read(buffer);
         return new String(buffer);
     }
```

reads just `len` bytes of your input stream.

Using [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library to convert the InputStream to a String directly:

```
 public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
     return IOUtils.toString(stream, "UTF-8");
 }
```